# Sortable items drag underneath other DOM elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I've got a page where users drag elements from one "pane" (a pool of items) into another pane (a list of items into one of which the pool items can be dragged).  I am moving, not copying items.

Think of assigning orders from an order well onto trucks.

Each of the sortable lists is divided into 2 tabs representing different types of orders (maybe bulk products vs. packaged products).

All of the moving among the various lists works great.  When the tab on one list changes from one order type to another, all of the tab controls change their active tab, too.

What is happening weird, though, is when I move an item from the left hand order well into the right hand assignment pane, the item slides under the DOM elements on the right side. However, as long as the mouse pointer is on the correct list, the item will be dropped correctly.

I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: It's hard to imagine or reproduce the problem from description, can you please post appropriate JSFiddle? I can help you. Worked a lot on ko-sortable before.

Comment: I know it's hard to visualize. I'll try to replicate it in JSFiddle.

Comment: It took way too long to get this done, but here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbelk/4kk0ejv6/

Comment: @RahulPatil: have you been able to take a look at this? I am completely stumped. Does it have anything to do with the number of containing divs before you get to my sortables?

Comment: The answer seems to lie somewhere in how the "overflow" CSS attribute is behaving.  If I don't explicitly set an overflow on the 2 left/right panes, then I can get items from the left side to the right, but it also means that if the list gets too long, it will just overflow the container.  I still can't get items moving from right to left to not "hide" because the overflow on the accordion is doing affecting them

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) of the items. When you're dragging an item, you probably want to make its `z-index` a high number temporarily.

Comment: I thought about that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try that out.